# limit the number of concurrent downloads in AFURLSessionManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, download

**Idea**

I'm building files download manager using AFNetworking and I'm using AFURLSessionManager class. the app is suppose to download mp3 files from the server.

I was concerned about memory consuming, so I'm trying to limit the number of simultaneous downloads to 1.

I know that there is a NSOperationQueue property in AFURLSessionManager called operationQueue and it's limited to 1 operation at a time by default.so I'm adding my NSURLSessionDownloadTask to operationQueue.

**the problem**

the code isn't working. files is being downloaded simultaneously instead of one after another.

**the code**

```
// 1. build sessionManager and prepare some vars
// note: by testing i found that it's better to init NSURLSessionConfiguration with backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier for memory issues 
NSURLSessionConfiguration *conf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"special_Identifier"];
AFURLSessionManager *manager    = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:conf];
NSURL *urlDocs                  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                         inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                                appropriateForURL:nil
                                                                           create:NO
                                                                            error:nil];
__block NSProgress *progress    = Nil;

// 2. open sessionManager operation Queue and add this new download
[manager.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // 2.1 init new download request
    NSURLRequest *request   = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileLink]];

    // 2.2 creat a NSURLSessionDownloadTask
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.downloadManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress
                                                                               destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
                                                                                   return [urlDocs URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                                                                               } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
                                                                                   if (!error) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"done: %@", filePath);
                                                                                   }else{
                                                                                       NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                                                                                   }
                                                                               }];

    // 2.3 start downloading
    [downloadTask resume];

    // 2.4 track downloading progress using KVO
    [progress addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(fractionCompleted))
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:(__bridge void *)(fileLink)];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In AFNetworking 2 (and AFNetworking 3), you can init your `AFHTTPSessionManager` with an `NSURLSessionConfiguration` (use `AFHTTPSessionManager initWithBaseURL:sessionConfiguration:`). There you can specify the number of connections per host (`HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost`).

Sample:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl.net"]; 
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration;
configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
AFHTTPSessionManager *sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
```

Documentation:

- AFHTTPSessionManager: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.0.4/Classes/AFHTTPSessionManager.html#//api/name/initWithBaseURL:sessionConfiguration:
- NSURLSessionConfiguration: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost